# Fastest method of building a timestamp of the current hour

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm looking for the fastest method to build a timestamp which represents the current hour starting from the current instant (in general, starting from a timestamp)

Currently I'm doing the following:

```js
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
var month = d.getUTCMonth();
var day = d.getUTCDate();
var hour = d.getUTCHours();
    
d = new Date(year, month, day, hour);
console.log(d);
console.log(d.getTime());
```

Is it possible to avoid the second invocation of Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want the timestamp of the beginning of the current hour. Then you could simply set the minutes and seconds to 0 in your first Date Object:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(0,0);
console.log(d);
console.log(d.getTime());
```

You could make it a oneliner, since [setMinutes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes) already returns a timestamp:

```
var timestamp = new Date().setMinutes(0,0);
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid calling date completely, if I start from a timestamp?

Comment: You would have to calculate the minutes+seconds from the given timestamp to subtract them. I don't know of an easier version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're doing that twice, you really don't need to.

```js
var d = new Date();

console.log(d.getHours());
// or
console.log(d.getTime() );
```

Comment: I need a new timestamp, your solution doesn't seem to answer, d.getTime is the current instant not the instant at the beginning of the hour